# Bean naming in Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, data-binding, spring-bean

As I understand it, in SB2 prefixes are required to be in kebab case due to stricter data binding requirements. What about bean names (i.e. @bean)? Are they required to in kebab case? I asked this because I was told this was the case, however I have my doubts and  I dont see anything mentioned about it on the SB2 migration page.

Answer (score 0):

Only configuration prefixing needs to be in kebab case. Bean names can rename camelcase.